# Sitemap Index versus Child Sitemaps

Tags: indexing, sitemap

I have a question about Sitemaps; More specifically a Sitemap Index that links Child Sitemaps...

I know through what I have read that if you submit your sitemap index to the webmaster tools in Google or Bing, the robots will eventually get around to processing the child sitemaps you have in your sitemap index. I have one Sitemap index and ten child sitemaps linked in the index. Everything is working and I do not get any errors. My question is... Is there any harm in submitting both the sitemap index and the child sitemaps to google? The reason I ask is I submitted the ten child sitemaps one by one... After I did all of that I learned that I should have a sitemap index (I'm still really new at web design) Should I be removing these child sitemaps from Google Webmaster Tools? Or can they just stay? I do not want to do something that will have a negative impact with search engines...

Any opinions on this topic would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0):

As per the [google support docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/71453?hl=en):

> As long as you've uploaded and saved all your Sitemaps, you don't need to submit each Sitemap individually. Just submit the Sitemap index file and you're good to go.

The downside of submitting the child sitemaps individually may be that, if you remove a child sitemap later you have to manually remove it. I can't actually verify that as I've not done it before.